# Mysql. Использовать результаты основного запроса в подзапросе

Tags: php, mysql, подзапрос

Есть таблица

```
id | man_id | year | house_id
1  | 10     | 2012 | 1
2  | 14     | 2011 | 5
3  | 12     | 2010 | 4
4  | 10     | 2010 | 3
5  | 15     | 2013 | 1
6  | 12     | 2012 | 3
```

Нужно получить список man_id, которые принадлежат одному house_id, но с тем учетом, что если искомый man_id есть и в других house_id, то выборка должна быть с условием, что year в искомом man_id должен быть больше, чем в других man_id. Если меньше, то в выборку не попадает.
Т.е. на выходе я должен получить (например, для house_id = 3)

```
id | man_id | year | house_id
6  | 12     | 2012 | 3
```

Объяснение по результату: ищем house_id=3. Он у нас в строках id=4 и id=6, у которых man_id=10 и man_id=12 соответственно. Рассмотрим сначала man_id=10: смотрим нет ли в таблице еще где man_id=10 и находим его у id=1, который относится к house_id=1 (т.е. не к house_id=3). А так как "year" у id=1 больше, чем у id=4, то в конечную выборку он (id=4) не попадает. Если year был бы больше, то в выборку бы попал. В выборку здесь попадет только строка с id=6, т.к. с man_id=12 есть строка id=4, у которой "year" меньше, чем у id=6. Получается, что запрос должен быть примерно таким:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE house_id='3' AND year > (чем year у другого id с таким же man_id [что и основном запросе], но другим house_id [что и основном запросе])
```

Это можно сделать одним основным запросом и кучей подзапросов на PHP:

```
$output_array = null;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE house_id='3'"); // выбираем все записи с house_id=3
if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $man_id = $data['man_id'];
      $year = $data['year'];
      $house_id = $data['house_id'];
      // выбираем записи с house_id не равным 3,
      // а также с выбранным из первого запроса man_id
      // и year больше выбранного в первом запросе
      $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE house_id != '$house_id'
                              AND man_id = '$man_id' AND year > '$year'");
      if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) { // если таких строк не нашлось,
                                           // то сохраняем выборку из первого запроса
          $output_array[] = $man_id;
      }
   }
}
print_r($output_array);
```

А как сделать то же самое, но только одним mysql-запросом, чтобы не плодить несколько сотен запросов на каждый вызов страницы, т.к. записей в таблице около 50 тыс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```sql
select
  *
from `table` as a
where house_id = 3 and
      not exists(
            select
              *
            from `table` as b
            where a.man_id = b.man_id and
                  a.house_id != b.house_id and
                  a.year < b.year
          );
```

Результат:

```
+----+--------+------+----------+
| id | man_id | year | house_id |
+----+--------+------+----------+
|  6 |     12 | 2012 |        3 |
+----+--------+------+----------+
```

[Демо](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=05a5192686a878cd151a55a6ca4f9de2).

Как поступать с `mai_id`, которых нет в других `house_id`?

Comment: Супер, то что надо! Я только немного его подправил - вместо "not exists(select * from ..." поставил "a.man_id NOT IN(select b.man_id FROM", что в принципе одно и то же. Спасибо! Значит я примерно на верном пути был. Остается только вопрос как быстро это будет работать, когда запрос перерисую на реальную таблицу, потому что здесь в принципе так же как и в PHP будет выполняться куча подзапросов, но только уже внутри mysql'я :) А man_id, которых нет в house_id, нужно добавлять в итоговую выборку, как этот запрос и делает.

Comment: Рад был помочь :)